# How to resolve : "Missing required flag -y in: W -t 100 "

Tags: simulation, wireless, ns2, topology

I'm running a simulation in ns2 and I'm getting the following error:

Missing required flag -x in: W -t 150
Missing required flag -y in: W -t 150
Parsing error in event. 
What exactly is leading to this error and how can I resolve it?

Comment: ... try adding "-y" flag?

Comment: yeah but where, I don't have any such statement "W -t 150" in the tcl script I am running.

Answer (score 0):

---

What are you trying to do ?

Expressions like "W -t 150" and "W -t 150" are not found in any known simulation examples.

All ~2000 examples https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNUUpUYWJ6TTdseWc/view?usp=sharing

---

Comment: I am simulating a WSN and moving node using setdest,
when I run the simulation, this appears on the console.
I think it is is related to setdest

Comment: Even I don't have this statement  "W -t 150"  in my script.

Answer (score 0):

---

"W -t " are usually only used for NAM, **in configuration files**. Never in simulation scripts.

```
$ cd All-examples/
$ grep "W -t" *
ns-lib.tcl:             $self puts-nam-config "W -t $stoptime"
ns-namsupp.tcl:         $self puts-nam-config "W -t * -x $maxX -y $maxY"
```

I.e. { ns-lib.tcl, ns-namsupp.tcl } are "lib" files : ns-2.3x/tcl/**

---

Comment: thanks and  yes I've not used it in script, but what I was trying to know is that why is it giving me such an error and how is it effecting execution of my script, 
And yes my files have same contents as it shows on ur console.